# dividers outside the parent divider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add two dividers inside another divider, yet I couldn't figure out how force the child dividers to be inside the parent divider.

How can I control the child dividers location inside the parent divider?

```css
#graph-container {
  border: solid;
}
#graph-info {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">

            <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="backgroundRed" data-toggle="tab">Main </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Main</div>
            <div class="container" id="graph_panel">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 bg-info " style="height: 800px;" id="graph-container">

                </div>
                <div class="container col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 bg-danger" style="height: 800px" id="graph-info">

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add width:auto to your #graph_panel

Answer (score 1):

You are already inside a `.container > .row` so it is not needed to add one more inside it.

[See this bootply fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/weYb4nUHpK)